# Can't find my VM instance after importing VM to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, vmware-vsphere, aws-cli

I followed the introductions from here

```
http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-4-esx-vcenter/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.vmadmin.doc_41/vc_client_help/importing_and_exporting_virtual_appliances/t_export_a_virtual_machine.html
```

to import my VM in VMWare Workstation to AWS. Then I used the following command to upload my VM image.

```
ec2-import-instance E:\CentOS-Elastix-64-disk1.vmdk  –f VMDK -t m2.micro -a x86_64 -b myawsbucket -o AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE -w wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY -p Linux`
```

It is successful to upload, and I can see the folder in my bucket, but in the AWS documentation, it says the VM instance will be created automatically. But I can't find where is my new VM. My VM is the Centos 64 bits.

Can anyone help me? Any help would be grateful.

Comment: Have you asked Amazon support? Are you sure you're looking in the correct region?

Comment: I didn't specify the location while uploading the vm. But my bucket is in the same region. Is it a problem? @EEAA

Comment: I agree with EEAA - if you haven't already opened a case with Amazon, try that first as they would be better placed to help. I've found them to be pretty good.

Comment: I think I find the problem. My bucket is in US standard region, but the region information shown on my dashboard is Oregon, the region might be different @EEAA

Comment: Even on free tier you can still use the AWS community forums, and Amazon does have a good history of responding when warranted.

Comment: Honestly I'd suggest a couple things: first, switch off of the old Java-based cli tools and use awscli instead. Second, read over the entire documentation for importing vmdks. Third, I know of a lot of people that use AWS. Not a single one is using this tool. Maybe deploying a vanilla server and then applying your config management to it would be faster.